# Sorting algorithm for large set of Server and Path

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, path

Working in C#, I would like to write an efficient sorting algorithm that would take as input a text file containing unsorted list of  server and path combinations and output a sorted file.

As an exercise, I am working under assumption that the input data size will exceed available memory, so I am thinking of reading the file into memory a chunk at a time, doing a Quick sort (or a Heap sort, maybe?), outputting sorted chunks to temporary files, then doing a merge sort to produce the final output.

The format of the input file is up to my discretion. It can be just a list of UNC paths (server and path as single string) or it can be a CSV with servers and paths as separate fields.

My question is whether there is any benefit to be had from having server and path be separate entities in my data structure and evaluating them separately?

Having server and path separate would eliminate having to compare the server names during the path comparison run, but require additional run to sort by server and, given the available memory constraint, would require me to somehow cache the sorted server lists, increasing disk IO overhead.

Is there some technique I can leverage to optimize performance of such an application by providing server and path as separate fields in my input?

Any other optimization techniques that I might consider given the nature of the dataset?

EDIT: This is a one-time task. I do not need to later look up the entries

Comment: Why not combine them? Sorting just `"Server\path"` is easiest.

Comment: Is this a one time or re-occurring task?  If one time, you should be able to just use server and see what the numbers look like.  (Sorting each server group would be very optimal).

Comment: Is it really necessary that you write a program for this? The Windows SORT command works quite well, provided your input data doesn't have lines longer than 65,535 characters. Type `sort /?` at the command line to get options. The [GNU CoreUtils](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm) sort is another option that works well. If you really need to do this yourself in C#, my series on [Sorting a large text file](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=674) might be of some use to you.

Comment: @JimMischel: Since the OP said "as an exercise" I assume that the purpose of writing this program is for self-teaching, rather than to solve a practical problem. The best way to solve the problem is, as you note, to use an off-the-shelf sorting utility or to dump the text into a database and have it do the sorting, or whatever.  Writing an on-disk sort algorithm is indeed a good exercise as its got both practical and theoretical problems to solve, but is doable by an individual in not much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am thinking of reading the file into memory a chunk at a time, doing a Quick sort (or a Heap sort, maybe?), outputting sorted chunks to temporary files, then doing a merge sort to produce the final output.

That's a perfectly reasonable plan.

An alternate solution would be: create an on-disk b-tree, and insert all your data one record at a time into the b-tree. You never need to have more than a few pages of the b-tree in memory and you can read the records one at a time from the unsorted list.  Once it's in the b-tree, read it back out in order.

> Having server and path separate would eliminate having to compare the server names during the path comparison run, but require additional run to sort by server and, given the available memory constraint, would require me to somehow cache the sorted server lists, increasing disk IO overhead.

OK.

> My question is whether there is any benefit to be had from having server and path be separate entities in my data structure and evaluating them separately?

You just said what the pros and cons are. You've already listed them. Why are you asking this question if you already know the answer?

> Is there some technique I can leverage to optimize performance of such an application by providing server and path as separate fields in my input?

Probably, yes.

> How can I know for sure?

Write the code both ways and run it. The one that is better will be observed to be better.

> Any other optimization techniques that I might consider given the nature of the dataset?

Your question and speculations are premature.

Start by setting a performance goal.

Then implement the code as clearly and correctly as you can.

Then carefully measure to see if you met your goal.

If you did, knock off early and go to the beach.

If you did not, get a profiler and use it to analyze your program to find the worst-performing part.  Then optimize that part.

Keep doing that until either you meet your goal, or you give up.

Comment: Or just type `sort <input-file >output-file` at the command line, and head to the beach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certainly not going to out-answer Eric Lippert, but from a novice's perspective I wonder if you're not looking for the most complex answer first.
You don't need to read the file into memory all at once with `File.ReadLines`...so your input is one line at a time. Use the `Uri` object for quick parsing of each string into it's component parts: host and path.

If you are thinking of a OO approach, then how about a 'serverUri' object that implements `IComparable` and having a `SortedList` of path strings. Make a `SortedList` of the serverUri objects, so that part of the string is stored only once, and for each path with that server uri, add it to the sub collection. Viola...its all sorted...spit it out to disk.